# Django - List index out of range

Tags: python, django, arrays, django-models

I have a ManyToManyField in my model. I need to get the third item for every query as below.

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    staff_job_categories = models.ManyToManyField(StaffJobCategory)
    staff_titles = models.ManyToManyField(PersonTitle, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_job_categories(self):
          return self.staff_job_categories.all()[3]
```

I use the get_job_categories function for admin list_filter but I want to show only the 3rd item in every many to many array.

But get the 
  **`List index out of range`** ERROR;
by the way;

```
def get_job_categories(self):
    return self.staff_job_categories.all()[:3]
```

Works fine. but gets all the objects till i get what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for jobs binded to less than 3 categories:

```
return ( self.staff_job_categories.all()[2] 
         if self.staff_job_categories.count() >= 3 
         else None
       )
```

Or:

```
return ( self.staff_job_categories.all()[2] 
         if len( self.staff_job_categories.all()[:3] ) >= 3 
         else None
       )
```

To avoid all categories recount.

Answer (score 0):

The first item in a sequence has index 0. The third item has index 2. Perhaps that's your only problem?

E.g. try:

```
def get_job_categories(self):
    return self.staff_job_categories.all()[2]
```

However, this assumes that you know for certain that all staff have at least three job categories and that their order is predictable. Is that actually the case? I don't *think* Django's ManyToManyField gives you any guarantee about the order that the related objects will be returned.